# After installing libx11-dev I am not able to find Xlib.h

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, ubuntu-10.10

There are lots of post here but none of them have helped me.

I have successfully installed `libx11-dev` from apt-get and still netbeans complaining that it cannot find include file `<X11/Xlib.h>`.

Also I have tried find xlib.h and there is no Xlib.h file nor X11 folder on my hard disk.

```
find / X11 
find / Xlib.h
```

Is there somenthing I should be looking at to fix it? I am using ubuntu 12 and it is a c/c++ project.

Comment: Please run this command and tell us what it prints:  `dpkg -L libx11-dev; COLUMNS=500 dpkg -l libx*-dev | awk '{print $1, $2}'`

Comment: Found the problem. I found the librarie in /usr/include/X11. After including this path to the include directories in netbeans it fixed the problem. I believed that all files including those inside of sub folders of /usr/include where automatically found.

Comment: Aha.  Meanwhile I've confirmed that `libx11-dev` was the correct thing to install, and I've written you an answer explaining why your `find` commands didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about netbeans, but:  you can find out what's in a package installed on your system with the command

```
dpkg -L <name of package>
```

When I do this on an Ubuntu system I have access too, it indicates that libx11-dev is *supposed* to include the file `/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h`.  However, this does not tell you if the file actually exists.  You need something like the `find` commands you were trying for that.

Now, your `find` commands didn't do anything because `find` has a command line syntax that's different from everything else.  This is how to do what you were trying to do with `find`:

```
find / -name Xlib.h -print
find / -name X11 -print
```

(On recent systems with GNU userland (i.e. all Linux and some others), the trailing `-print` is not necessary, but on older systems and possibly also those that retain more of a BSD heritage, it is.  I learned my shell back in the bad old days of SunOS 4 and I still have those habits.)